# Swift binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two CGFloat operands

Tags: swift, types, cgfloat

I am writing a function in Swift to detect which hexagon I am clicking on. But I ran into a peculiar error message stating that I cannot add two CGFloats. Whatever I did, e.g. changing `let` to `var`, declare and assign separately, did not work. I guess there must be something else wrong, but I cannot find it. The code is as follows:

```
func pointToCoordinate(position: CGPoint) -> (Int, Int) {
        var gridHeight = 2 * singleRadius / sqrt(CGFloat(3)) * 1.5
        var gridWidth = 2 * singleRadius
        var halfWidth = singleRadius

        var relativePosition = CGPoint(x: position.x - totalRadius / 2, y: position.y - totalRadius / 2)
        println((relativePosition.y / gridHeight))
        var row = -(cgfloatToInt)(relativePosition.y / gridHeight)
        var column: Int

        println((relativePosition.x + halfWidth * CGFloat(row + 1)) / (gridWidth))
        column = cgfloatToInt((relativePosition.x + halfWidth * CGFloat(row + 1)) / (gridWidth))

//        var innerY: CGFloat = CGFloat(relativePosition.y) + CGFloat(gridHeight * row)
        var innerX = relativePosition.x
        var innerY = relativePosition.y

        innerY = innerY - CGFloat(gridHeight * row)

        println((innerX, innerY))
        return (column, row)
    }
```

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The error message is wrong.  The problem is that you are trying to multiply an `Int` and a `CGFloat`.

Replace:

```
innerY = innerY - CGFloat(gridHeight * row)
```

with:

```
innerY = innerY - gridHeight * CGFloat(row)
```

---

The answer above is for the current version of your code.  For the commented out version that corresponds to the error message you posted:

Replace:

```
var innerY: CGFloat = CGFloat(relativePosition.y) + CGFloat(gridHeight * row)
```

with

```
var innerY: CGFloat = CGFloat(relativePosition.y) + gridHeight * CGFloat(row)
```

Comment: "The error message is wrong" is still very relevant regarding this same message in Xcode 8/Swift 3.

Comment: @SpaceDog I find Swift compiler errors run the gamut from telling you what you need to know, accurate but only helpful to a compiler writer, and flat out wrong. This case was flat out wrong.

Comment: @vacawama - I was by adding a CGFloat to a Float a few moments ago and the error message was "binary operator + cannot be applied to CGFloat" what is a bullcrap message. The correct message would have to be "you cannot add CGFloats and Floats". Binary operator is a confuse term because you think of binary operations. I create apps since 2008. I never saw a single Xcode error message pointing to the correct problem. They are all created to inflict maximum pain.

Answer (score 5):

Looking through all the answers, castings, conversion and extensions, I think the best solution yet to say for Swift is **Operator Overload**. Code sample below for Swift 3.0:

```
/// overloads -/+ between a cgfloat on the left and an int/double on the right
func - (left: CGFloat, right: Double) -> CGFloat {
    return left - CGFloat(right);
}

func - (left: CGFloat, right: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return left - CGFloat(right);
}

func + (left: CGFloat, right: Double) -> CGFloat {
    return left + CGFloat(right);
}

func + (left: CGFloat, right: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return left + CGFloat(right);
}
```

Put this into a global place **OUTSIDE** of any class. See magic occurs.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, there is something else wrong, this works:

```
import QuartzCore

let a:CGFloat = 1
let b:CGFloat = 2

let c = a + b
var innerY: CGFloat = CGFloat(1.0) + CGFloat(2.0)
```

and `CGFloat` implements the `FloatingPointType` type

Answer (score 2):

iOS 15, Swift 5.x

I had this problem, was solved by unwrapping the value... the floats in my case were optionals.

Answer (score 1):

Late to join. Based on vacawama's answer, you all know the problem is not having the same data type.
`CGFloat` needs to be written multiple times sometimes. I found this easier via extension. So sharing an answer. You can create a simple extension like below. Ofcourse, this extension can be further modified.

```
import CoreGraphics
extension Int {
    var cgf: CGFloat { return CGFloat(self) }
    var f: Float { return Float(self) }
}

extension Float {
    var cgf: CGFloat { return CGFloat(self) }
}

extension Double {
    var cgf: CGFloat { return CGFloat(self) }
}

extension CGFloat {
    var f: Float { return Float(self) }
}
```

Now we can write

```
innerY = innerY - gridHeight * row.cgf
```